# IE11 not positioning my box in correct position. Workaround?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

when I use `left:15%` on one of my box placements, it shows up exactly where it should be in all browsers, except IE. I'm using IE 11, so i'm not sure if it is also not working in previous versions of ie.

i've never added an exception for a browser before.

how would i add this: `left: 20%`

just for internet explorer, probably all version i'm thinking.

here is the page I'm referencing for visual reference.
http://alleystoeden.org/testing3/contact-photographer-nina-sutherland.html

Comment: Please explain where exactly it is supposed to be. Screenshots would be great.

Comment: Targeting a browser is never a good idea. The old ie6/ie7 hacks were truly that: hacks. You should target features. In the case of `left` or `margin-left` that shouldn't even be necessary. Find out why they act differently.

Comment: It looks exactly the same to me in IE11 and Chrome. So yeah, will definitely need a screenshot :) On a side-note, that photo is beautiful.

Comment: @rudie conditional comments were not quite hacks... Ms created them specifically for developers to write code to target versions of IE.

Comment: I meant CSS hacks like `*height` and `_height` in IE6 and 7. I'm sure you remember. IE11 doesn't need those things anymore, so there's a deeper problem. (Or none at all.) It's personal of course.

Comment: i want it centered under the logo "nina sutherland". i was reading and found that the absolute positioning inside a relative parent will keep it in the right left position. unfortunately, that's when i realized that the logo, as the window is resized, moves so it will require me to figure out how to keep the logo and menu in place without moving through the different screen resolutions. i'm not really sure even where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting a specific browser, try to find and fix the problem.

For example, try `margin-left` instead of `left`. Functionally it should do the same. Maybe more xbrowser.

```
.box {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

Comment: How on earth is `left` not cross-browser?

Comment: That's not what I said. Potential bugs with `left` are not xbrowser. In this case it's also more appropriate.